# Can a view auto-identify the table name(s) on which it is based ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, objectid

Wonder if someone might be able to help me. I'm trying to build a view on a table that allows me to put the table name as an extra column into that view. I can do this through a manual process by mentioning'`TableName' AS ColumnA`, but I'm trying to see if there is a way that I can get SQL to grab the Table name from its own query to add this as a column.

Comment: Share example of table structure and view query

Comment: What if this is a View with joins in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes (see example below). The long answer is that may depend upon how your view is constructed.

If you're on SQL Server 2008 or greater, you can use [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677185.aspx) to get dependency info for a DB object.

Let's try it with a view:

```
create table myTable (myColumn int, myOtherColumn char(1));
insert into myTable select 1, 'a';
insert into myTable select 2, 'b';

create view myView as
select t.*, e.referenced_entity_name
from myTable t
    join sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.myView', 'OBJECT') e
        on e.referenced_minor_id = 0;

select * from myView;
```

Results:

```
myColumn myOtherColumn referenced_entity_name
-------- ------------- ----------------------
       1 a             myTable
       2 b             myTable

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Will this simple example fit your usage? Please let us know.

Comment: This has Answered my specific question, as I'm only looking to do this based on one table, so thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

No. The problem with this, may be that, a view can draw upon multiple tables. You are looking for Me.parent.name or this.parent.name. More precisely, Me.parents(0), Me.parents(1) and so, based on all tables that were joined to create a view. Also, a view can be based on other views. Then, the reference would look like :Me.parents_at_up_level(0).name, if the view at dependency level 3, wants to look at its great-grandfather-table-name. Nevertheless, a good idea and good thinking, this should have been possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're working with a set of tables that have at least 1 column in common. In such case, you are probably using a coalesce function to determine the value of that column. In such cases you can use a case block to track the table it came from. Something similar to the below might work for you:

```
CASE WHEN a.col <> '' THEN 'Table A'
     WHEN b.col <> '' THEN 'Table B'
     WHEN c.col <> '' THEN 'Table C'
     ELSE 'Table D'
END AS colA,
COALESCE(a.col, b.col, c.col, d.col) AS colB
```

I hope this at least points you in the right direction.

C§